# Change CMD title back to what it originally was (Batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get my batch script to change the title of the Command Prompt to change back to what it was before my script started.

Here's an example:

```
@echo off
title My Script
REM rest of script here
:end
title %origcmdtitle%
```

So before it would run, it would have its default title; something like `Command Prompt` or `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`

Then, when my script runs, the title changes to `My Script`

Finally, when the script ends, I want it to change back to the original title of CMD (it just stays as `My Script`)

Thanks!

Comment: So what methods have you come up with, that's your job. We help you with your code where you are stuck, we don't research methods for you and wrote it. (The easiest method is don't change the title in the first place, it's unnecessary in the grand scheme of things. _One doesn't look at the mantle piece when you're poking the fire_.)

Comment: @Compo eh, I'll pass.

Comment: @ditheredtransparency, so six months later and neither of these answers solved your problem?

Comment: Again, Squashman, these did not completely solve the issue. They helped, but did not solve the issue.

But just because it bothers you so much, I accepted the answer that helped me most.

Comment: @ditheredtransparency LOL, nobody? Use this and your problem is solved: title %comspec%

Comment: @FifthAxiom there was already an answer post that suggested this (so: no. not "nobody"), and unfortunately it was just as wrong as you in that command prompt instances can be started with a title that's _different_ from the default title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has always been one of many thorny issues with writing batch code.

I've seen some fairly involved code to attempt to discern the current title and save the value in a variable so that the title could be restored before the batch script ends. But I have never been thoroughly satisfied with those results.

I think the most robust and straight forward approach is to launch the script within a new cmd.exe session, where you can then set the title with impunity. Once your script ends, the child process will end, and the original cmd.exe process will resume control with the original title restored.

You can have a script relaunch itself within a new cmd.exe session if you employ a "unique" extra parameter to signal that the relaunch has occurred. You can then use SHIFT to restore the original arguments.

Here is a trivial example:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" equ ":SET-TITLE" goto %1
cmd /c "%~f0" :SET-TITLE %*
exit /b

:SET-TITLE
shift /1
title myTitle
echo %%1=%1  %%2=%2
pause
exit /b
```

There are a couple potential problems with this method.

- Any command line arguments are parsed multiple times, which could be problematic if there are escaped poison characters. The escapes would have to be doubled.
- It is not possible for environment variable changes made by the script to survive after the script terminates, unless you write the variables to a file, and then reload the values from the file once you return to the parent session.

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I'm just a little confused with the potential issues with this method. Is it ok if you explain them, please?

Comment: @ditheredtransparency 1) `normal.bat a^^b` will receive `a^b` in `%1`, but   `thisSolution.bat a^b` will receive `ab` in `%1` because of extra round of parsing. 2) Some batch files are designed to set a variable value that persists after the script terminates. That is impossible with this solution unless you resort to a temporary file.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some example code using a method of determining the PID of the current command window; *(developed over on [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6133&start=30#p38870) by [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) a couple of years ago)*.

```cmd
@Echo Off
Set "_PI="
Call :getPID _PI
If Not Defined _PI GoTo :EOF
Set "_WT="
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In ('TaskList /FI "PID EQ %_PI%" /V /FO LIST'
) Do Set "_WT=%%B"
If Not Defined _WT GoTo :EOF
Set "_WT=%_WT:~1%"
Echo( CURRENT TITLE IS: %_WT%
Timeout 5 /NOBREAK>Nul
Title NEW TITLE
Echo( A NEW TITLE HAS BEEN GIVEN
Timeout 5 /NOBREAK>Nul
Title %_WT%
Echo( THE ORIGINAL TITLE HAS BEEN RESTORED
Timeout 5 /NOBREAK>Nul
GoTo :EOF

:getPID  [RtnVar]
::
:: Store the Process ID (PID) of the currently running script in environment variable
:: RtnVar. If called without any argument, then simply write the PID to stdout.
::
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
:getLock
set "lock=%temp%\%~nx0.%time::=.%.lock"
set "uid=%lock:\=:b%"
set "uid=%uid:,=:c%"
set "uid=%uid:'=:q%"
set "uid=%uid:_=:u%"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "uid=!uid:%%=:p!"
endlocal & set "uid=%uid%"
2>nul ( 9>"%lock%" (
  for /f "skip=1" %%A in (
    'wmic process where "name='cmd.exe' and CommandLine like '%%<%uid%>%%'" get ParentProcessID'
  ) do for %%B in (%%A) do set "PID=%%B"
  (call )
))||goto :getLock
del "%lock%" 2>nul
endlocal & if "%~1" equ "" (echo(%PID%) else set "%~1=%PID%"
exit /b
```

Comment: This does work well, except that it seems to store the name of the script and then restore that. (For example, it would go from `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`, to `My Title`, and then restore as `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - script`)

Comment: Just split the variable as necessary at **` -` or `- script`**, if yours does that. There are plenty of examples of how to do that on here. _(Out of interest how are you invoking the script, my test using that code doesn't have that behavior)._

Comment: I'll give that a try and report back with what I have. To invoke the script, I just copied your code into a new batch file and ran it from CMD.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure what I need to change to take off the `-`

Comment: TBF, I'm inclined to think that the script name is being added separately to the window title. If I remember correctly you get Administrator: or similar prepended to the original title if you `Run as administrator`. If that's the case that solution may not work, or at least be a hack.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Andreas should be upvoted, since it is very good at actually fetching the current cmd window title.

The answer may be furter refined, to avoid needing a temporary file:

```
@REM Store current title in variable title_org
for /F "tokens=1 delims=- USEBACKQ" %%i in (`powershell -noprofile -command "[system.console]::title"`) do set title_org=%%i

title My title
echo do some work

@REM Restore title
title %title_org%
```

Please note that the commands above must be used inside a batch file. If testing the command in an interactive command window, the %%i must be reduced to just %i:

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=- USEBACKQ" %i in (`powershell -noprofile -command "[system.console]::title"`) do set title_org=%i
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using PowerShell to store the original title in a file, then read the title back into a variable.

Here is an example:

```
powershell -noprofile -command "[system.console]::title">%TEMP%\~wndtitle.tmp
for /F "tokens=1 delims=-" %%i in (%TEMP%\~wndtitle.tmp) do set title_org=%%i
title This is a test!
pause
title %title_org%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to simply restore the default title:

`title %ComSpec%`

Comment: `%comspec%` = `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`, Cmd window default title = `Eingabeaufforderung` (German) or `Command Prompt` (English) and `what it was before my script started` could be literally anything.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is:

```
@echo off
rem set your title
title My Sublime Title
pause
rem reset title to the default value
title %comspec%
```

Comment: No, it is not. That resets it to the _default_ title, but command prompt instances can be started with a completely different title. For example, running `start "test" cmd /k "dir"` starts a new command prompt with the title "test".