# The Window Title of Command Prompt

Tags: cmd

I don't want the window title name of the command line to change. When i make shortcut or open it in different location, window title name of cmd is changing. How can i stop it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In short: you can't. CMD.EXE internally calls [`SetConsoleTitle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletitle) (or some equivalent), and there isn't an option to stop it from doing so.

What you can do is manually reset the title after each command (for example when you run a batch file with multiple commands inside and want to end up with some specific title). Use the [`title`](https://ss64.com/nt/title.html) command to do so from within a batch file or from the command prompt interactively.

(There are also more [involved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42590265/21567) options, but they all have quirks.)

I *think* some console alteratives (like [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) or [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)) let specify that the title should not change, but I'm not sure, you'll have to try.

Maybe clarify your question with what you are really trying to achieve, or why the changing title is an issue for you.

Comment: I'm using a program that blocks any process from running. This program makes process-based restrictions and uses the window title name. So when the window title name is changed, it cannot prevent the process from running.

Comment: Hmm, ... OK. But frankly using the Window title name for such restrictions does some like a very weak measure anyway. Sorry, but I cannot help you there further. Maybe you should ask a new question with the information from your previous comment. Maybe someone can give better advice then. (Might be a typical case of [X/Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)